# Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory tic_tac_toe

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может у кого была данная ошибка? SDK вроде как стоит. Поменял Platform Toolset. До этого выбивало

> The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found

Comment: Ну так поставьте Platform Toolset. Вероятно, SDK и DDK надо ставить.

Comment: Измените целевую платформу на ту,  SDK которой у вас установлена. Если это студия 2017, то на 10.16299